# Switch not carrying over parts of an input?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

My assignment for my class is to convert letters to numbers from an input file, like an old phone's keypad. i.e ABC are 2, DEF are 3, etc.

So, in the input file, one of the inputs is `1-800-ARID`.

Using `switch`, I was able to successfully change the characters into numbers, but am unable to carry over the `1-800`, or rather I'm not aware how to do so, or if it is even possible to carry over.

So far, I have this:

```cpp
while(input.eof()){
    input.get(ch);
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': output << '2'; break;
        case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': output << '3'; break;
        case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': output << '4'; break;
        case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': output << '5'; break;
        case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': output << '6'; break;
        case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': output << '7'; break;
        case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': output << '8'; break;
        case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z': output << '9'; break;
    }
```

Running `1-800-ARID` through this returns just `2743`, without the prefix of `1-800`.

Comment: The `switch` will ignore everything that is not a capital letter. Either add a `case '1':` (and `'2'` ... etc) or a `default:` to handle the other characters.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to implement default. The only way I can think of is to do "1-800-" but would that not just print 1-800- every time there is no capital letter? @dxiv

Comment: @learningtocode65 You are outputting characters one by one. So if you see a `'1'` then output a `'1'`. If you see a `'-'` then output a `'-'`. If you see a `ch` then... you get the idea.

Comment: Make the default case just print `ch` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting ONLY the characters you convert, nothing else. Simply add a `default` block to the `switch` to output all other characters as-is.

Also, your use of `input.eof()` is wrong.

Try this:

```cpp
while (input.get(ch)){ // <— fixed
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': output << '2'; break;
        case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': output << '3'; break;
        case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': output << '4'; break;
        case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': output << '5'; break;
        case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': output << '6'; break;
        case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': output << '7'; break;
        case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': output << '8'; break;
        case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z': output << '9'; break;
        default: output << ch; break; // <— add this
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up stumbling upon this just by messing around with the code/thinking a little harder about the problem. Thank you. I'm still new to this site so I'm not sure if I have to @ you or not.